How to setup memory cgroup with OOM killer enabled?
I did the following:
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test
echo 32212254720 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test/memory.limit_in_bytes
cgexec -g memory:test …

But when the cgroup's memory is almost fully used, then processes start to degrade but no OOM happens:
❯ cat memory.limit_in_bytes 
32212254720
❯ cat memory.usage_in_bytes 
32197885952
❯ cat memory.oom_control 
oom_kill_disable 0
under_oom 0
oom_kill 0

In htop all the processes are shown in uninterruptable state (D sign).
How to properly setup cgroup to let the OOM killer do it's job and kill processes?

I don't know if you can assign an OOM killer to a specific cgroup without setting up a full container including an OOM service, but if you have a system wide OOM killer running, it should work on what is in the container.
